# zio sqs message attributes

Tags: scala, zio

i,
I have consume method like:

```
private def consume(queueUrl: String) =
        SqsStream(
          queueUrl,
          SqsStreamSettings(
            stopWhenQueueEmpty = false,
            waitTimeSeconds = Some(3),
            visibilityTimeout = Some(sqsConfig.visibilityTimeout),
            autoDelete = false,
            messageAttributeNames = List("TEST", AWSTraceHeader.unwrap.toString)
          )
        ).mapError(AwsError.fromThrowable)
```

and I send message to the queue:

> aws sqs send-message --endpoint-url
> "https://sqs.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/666"
> --queue-url "https://sqs.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/666/queue-name"
> --message-body '{ "event_type": "create", "user_id": "666" }' --message-attributes "AWSTraceHeader={StringValue=TestTenant,DataType=String}"

and message.attributes gives me an empty map.. what I do wrong ? thanks!

Comment: I think it would be better to ask in the github of the library.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez asked already, trying whereever I can ;)

Answer (score 2):

I should use `message.messageAttributes` ;) dummy mistake.